# Android Terminal: Vibration command?

Tags: terminal, command-line, vibration

Which command in the Android Terminal can be used to vibrate? (for a custom length such as 50 milliseconds)

I would like to integrate vibration feedback into a shell script.

Maybe I need permission first. How do I manually grant the Android Terminal permission?

Comment: Should this maybe be moved over to StackOverflow?

Comment: Shell scripts/command-line questions are on-topic here. No need to move or repost there. Are you open to app based suggestions? For e.g., you can set up a task in Tasker that would vibrate the phone the way you want, and you would be able to trigger that task from shell script as well.

Comment: @Firelord Sure, if I can integrate it into the shell script, an app-based solution also will be fine.

Comment: @FireLord: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418054/turn-on-vibration-by-terminal-command does already mention a command (`echo 200 > /sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/enable`), but the Android Terminal unfortunately has no permission to use it.

Comment: Sorry about Tasker. It has introduced some changes so it won't be possible to use it this way. As for the command you mentioned. I've tested it. It works well, but requires root access.

Comment: Hmm… @Firelord Maybe there is a command to request vibration engine access via the terminal. But the vibration feedback should be immediate and not delayed by 10 seconds, otherways that would make it less purposeful.